# Microsoft SQL Server Statistics via ODBC

Tags: sql-server, ruby, odbc, unixodbc

I have an instance of SQL Server that I am trying to benchmark. From the SQL Studio application I can type

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
```

and see outputted statistics after that. From C++ code, I can do something like

```
SQLExecDirect(hstmt, "SET STATISTICS TIME ON", SQL_NTS);
```

and then retrieve these statistics via `SQLError`.

Is there a way to get at these statistics when accessing SQL Server over vanilla ODBC. In this case I am using Ruby's `DBI:ODBC` connector which works fine to connect and run queries but I haven't been able to figure out this meta stuff.

Comment: This is a very interesting question +1

Comment: I'm confused.  ODBC is simply a function mapping shim between the underlying driver and the driver manager.  What works directly is identical to "vanilla ODBC".  Is the question related to the use of a third party ODBC driver such as FreeTDS to access SQLServer from a different platform or is it actually specific to Rubys DBI interface?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not going via odbc, but if you have the Sql Server tools, would the Sql Profiler work for you? You can use that to time the execution of statements, transactions, sprocs, and a myriad other things in Sql Server.

Comment: It has to go over ODBC. Thanks, though.

Comment: I assume there's an overriding reason for not using the robust tools provided by the database manufacturer...

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `dbh.func(:stat)`